# PHP Session expiration - works stand alone but not in a function

Tags: php, session, cookies

when I issue this code from a function, the cookies expire at the end of the session

```
$validuntil = '2024-02-17';
$validuntil = strtotime ($validuntil);
setcookie ('vid',$vid,$validuntil,'/');
setcookie ('pwd',$pwd,$validuntil,'/');
```

However, executing the *exact* same code in a stand alone php file sets the cookies to  expire on the correct date.

Here is the function

```
function validuser ($vid, $pwd){
 global $pdo;

 $stmnt = $pdo->prepare ("select * from members where vid = :vid and password = :password");
 $stmnt->bindParam (':vid',$vid);
 $stmnt->bindParam (':password', $pwd);

 $stmnt->execute();

 if ( $stmnt->rowCount() != 1){
    header("Location:invalid.php");
    break;
 }

 $member = $stmnt->fetch (PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if ($member->nickname!="")
       $_SESSION['user']= $member->nickname." ".$member->lname;
    else
       $_SESSION['user']= $member->fname." ".$member->lname;


    $validuntil = '2024-02-17';
    $validuntil = strtotime ($validuntil);
    setcookie ('vid',$vid,$validuntil,'/');
    setcookie ('pwd',$pwd,$validuntil,'/');

    $_SESSION['ulot']  = $member->ulot;
    $_SESSION['valid'] = '101150';
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $member->admin == 1;
    $_SESSION['vid']   = $member->vid;
    $_SESSION['resid'] = $member->vid;
    $_SESSION['pwd']   = $member->pwd;
    $_SESSION['user']  = $member->fname." ".$member->lname;
    header ("Location:mainmenu.php");
```

}

Can someone please explain this and how I fix it.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show your function code?

Comment: Cookies are only set if the headers are not yet sent - are you sure, you have no output sent before the function is called?

Comment: did you remember to pass in `$vid` and `$pid` to your function?

Comment: Remember please, the cookies work just fune until the browesr is closed so I know that they work.  They just expire at the wrong time

Comment: How do you know the cookies work fine, are you sure you are not using the session instead? You should check the return value of `setcookie()`. Also, you should never store passwords in cookies (I wouldn't store them in sessions either...) and you need to `exit();` after a `header` redirect to avoid execution of code that comes after that redirect.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, if I don't store passwords in cookies, where do I store them?  How do Stack Overflow, Amazon, etc. remember my login info?

When I log off of my site, and then log back in, I say $userid = ($_COOKIE['uid'] and the proper info is returned.  So I conclude that $uid is coming from the cookie.

Didn't know about using exit() after a re-direct.  Thanks